# Single user cannot access Server Folders by Domain Name

Tags: active-directory, domain

I have encountered an issue where a single user in the Domain cannot access Shared Folders when referring to the Server by it's Domain Name. Normally, a user simply needs to type in the Server Name into the address bar:

> \\SVR01-DC

However, we have one user that cannot access the server this way (not any of the shared folders) by addressing it using the Domain Name. They can however access the folders by using the IP.

The setup for this user is as such:

- They are a Domain User, and have logged into the Domain. I.e. DOMAIN\User
- The Server they are trying to access is on a separate subnet to the Laptop they are trying to access it from. (Server - 192.168.1.0; Laptop - 192.168.2.0)
- Other users on the same subnet as the Client Laptop have no issues accessing the server by the Domain Name.
- The user in question has no issue accessing other servers on the same or different subnets in this manner. (I.e. "\\SVR01-APP" (Subnet 1) or "\\SVR02-DC" (Subnet 2) have no issue connecting).

I have not tried connecting to the Server through the same user on a different PC, however when the Laptop is moved to the same office as the Server in question, it has no issue connecting to the Server by it's Domain Name.

No other discrepancies or issues that I have been able to stand out in the settings for Shares, User Access or Group Policy for this user, and the solutions outlined in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/407929/getting-the-target-account-name-is-incorrect-when-accessing-a-share-on-the-des) do not apply - as far as I can tell all services/settings are working as intended.

**EDIT:** A similar issue has arisen in the other direction. A single user (different login in, different PC), has lost access to the SVR02-DC Server, while on Subnet 1.

Additionally, in investigating this, I have found that both users can access the Server(s) via IP, rather than Domain Name.

Comment: What OS is running on the client? What is the client using for DNS?

Comment: @joeqwerty the client is running Windows 10 (as are all others), and the server is running 2012R2. There was some record of updates being applied, but I am uncertain of the time frame in correlation with these issues.

Comment: @joeqwerty as for DNS that is being managed by the Domain Controller. They are joined to the Domain, not a Workgroup (since they are using Pro, not Home edition of Windows 10). The entry in the DNS is correct for both Server and Client PC, with the correct Names and IPs

Comment: Do you have some other DC for try connect? Did you review the user's permissions? Check SYSVOL permission. Other user in the same PC has the same problem? Try the same user in other workstation in the same subnet, and other user in the same workstation where is the problem, for you can define if the problem is the computer or the user account. Also you can try a DCDIAG and look for some problem in the results. Did you check the system logs in the DC?